# Define a custom launch image when app relaunches from the background mode

Tags: ios, background

Would it be possible to use a different launch image when app relaunches from the background mode?
If so, how to make it happen?
It's not about the different device orientation. 
I've searched around but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add your launch image in this method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}
```

Its on your app's delegate.